# How to fix the error when used golang + vscode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

enter image description hereI wish to use the vscode to type golang,
so I set both, then I added the go plugins in vscode,
but it shows these error, I don't know how to fix it.
Is there any knows it?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOQQv.jpg)

[plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JN88x.png)

[setting.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCSRA.png)

[go env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhreL.png)

Comment: Your package path or GOROOT/GOPATH environment variables look misconfigured. Look at the package that is trying to be loaded: `_/d_/Work/src` and it is looking for that package inside of: `D:\go\src\_\d_\Work\src`. You should really be posting code snippets instead of images as well

Comment: @rickjerrity I checked my Go env ,  I haven't found the issue.Is there any mistake?

Comment: Is your `helloworld.go` in a proper package directory in GOPATH? (also, please stop pasting pictures of text)

Comment: @JimB  Yes, the helloworld.go is path $GOPATH/src/

Comment: @DreamWalker_1989: that is not a valid location. Create a package directory in `src/` and try there.

Comment: @JimB Thanks.I have tried it.But the console still shows that go build xxx: build out "xx\\go-code-check" already exists and is not an object file.DO you know what's it means?

Comment: Something is trying to build the file `go-code-check`, which already exists (though I haven't seen that error in years, do possibly have multiple version of Go installed?). If it's a temp file, you can probably remove it. The fact that you have GOPATH set to `D:\Work`, but the error thinks the package should be in `D:\Work\src\_\d_\Work\src` looks like a problem too.

Comment: @JimB I have more than 100 error prompts to show that " build out "xx\\go-code-check" already exists and is not an object file ". I have tried to remove it, but it doesn't work.There was a 1.7 version of GO before, and I had uninstalled it then installed 1.10 version.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the solution.
You can open the user's settings.json file in the visual code , then

```
set "go.buildOnSave": true,
set "go.lintOnSave": true,
set "go.vetOnsave":false
```

I hope it can help you